# Как правильно удалить Windows7 рядом с XP?

Tags: windows, windows-7

В свое время поставил кроме ХР еще и 7. Потом понял, что 7 мне не нужна, занимает место, хочу освободиться от нее. Но вот беда, простым форматированием диска с 7 прошлый раз я избавлялся не только от нее, но и не мог вообще ХР восстановить, где-то какая-то инфа хранилась и на том диске, типа `boot.ini`. Искал в интернете, но толком нормального ответа не нашел. Сообщение о выборе оси можно убрать, но все же неприятно думать, что на диске еще что-то ненужное есть. Подскажите кто как этот вопрос решал, а то боюсь потерять ХР, уж очень много на ней программ и т.п.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если 7 установлена на другом диске (разделе), то смело его форматируешь, затем загружаешься с установочного диска ХР (как при установке). Когда появится надпись "нажмите R для восстановления" - нажимаешь и попадаешь в консоль восстановления. Набираешь на клаве fixboot, нажимаешь "ввод". После выполнения команды набираешь fixmbr - "ввод". По окончании набери exit - комп перезагрузится. Мне в аналогичной ситуации помогло.

Comment: Скоро опробую. Спасибо, отмечу как ответ после практического применения)